# Using python how to add enough rows and columns to an image/array, so that I can always divide the input image in to segments of required shape?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have an image of shape 512x512, I should add 8 more rows and 8 more columns to it to make it's shape 520x520. so that the image can be divided in to segments of 40x40 shape.

**Using code :**

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_blocks
import gdal

ds = gdal.Open('D:\512.tiff')
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
arr1 = band.ReadAsArray()
arr1.shape
>>(512,512)
arr2 = np.zeros((8,512), dtype='float32')
arr3=np.vstack((arr1,arr2))
arr4=np.zeros((520,8), dtype='float32')
arr=np.hstack((arr3,arr4))
arr.shape
>>(520,520)
#Now, I can use this command to divide the image in to segements each of shape of 40x40 :
img= view_as_blocks(arr, block_shape=(40,40))
```

Here my problem is, always I want to divide the image in to segments of shape 40x40 but always my input image will not be of same size(512x512) ie. it can be (512x516) (529x517) or anything.

So my code requirement is that the code should be able to read the shape of the input image and it must automatically add 'n' no.of rows and columns required to make my image in to segments of shape 40x40

Comment: Hint: The modulo operator `%` may help here.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to use it.

Comment: Modulo operator `a % b` returns the remainder of a division `a / b`. Therefore `a - a % b` is always dividable by `b` because the possible remainder is removed.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelButscher I was able to achieve  my requirement with this but if I don't want to delete the rows and columns and add them (with zero values)instead what can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ceiling function for this:

```py
import math
import numpy as np
new_width = int(math.ceil(float(arr1.shape[1])/segment_width)*segment_width)
new_height = int(math.ceil(float(arr1.shape[0])/segment_height)*segment_height)
new_arr1 = np.zeros((new_height, new_width), dtype=arr1.dtype)
new_arr1[:arr1.shape[0], :arr1.shape[1]] = arr1
```

The `float` conversion is just to make sure there is a `float` division and is not necessary in python 3.